# How to catch this text with Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, css, parsing, jsoup

I'm going crazy just for trying to extract some text from this source code:

`<tr class="even">
    <!-- Title -->
    <td class="title riot" title="Summoners, We will be performing Live Maintenance on the 26/11 at 04:00 AM, where we will need to bring the EUW Platform offline. Following up...">`

I've tried a lot of combinations of constructors, but I can't really do this without any advice... I need to catch the text between the " after title...

Please, note that there's a similar class, called "odd", that has the same syntax of the first one, and this is it:

```
<tr class="odd">
<!-- Title -->
<td class="title riot" title="Summoners, welcome to the Service Status forum! Here you can come to see information regarding ongoing issues or events that we are currently working...">
```

So, I need something that can catch the text written on the both classes...

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:** Here's my code, where I connect and catch some links:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/forumdisplay.php?f=10")
                                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22")
                                    .timeout(30000).get();
                    Elements links = doc.select("a[href*=thread]");
                    for (Element link : links){
                        if(link.attr("href").contains("board")||link.attr("href").contains("page")||link.text().matches("1")){}
                        else{
                            titles.add((String) link.text());

                            //descriptions.add((String) DEFAULT_FORUM_URL + link.attr("href"));
                            descriptions.add((String) doc.select("[title*=a]").toString());
                        }
                    }
```

The commented line writes on each second row of a ListView , the link of the thread, but I need to write there thr brief description that is between those tags "td class="title riot" title=", from each class.

Naturally, this line

```
descriptions.add((String) doc.select("[title*=a]").toString());
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/forumdisplay.php?f=10").get();

for (Element element : doc.select("tr.odd > td, tr.even > td")) {
    System.out.println(element.attr("title"));
}
```

Which will output:

```
Summoners, welcome to the Service Status forum! Here you can come to see information regarding ongoing issues or events that we are currently working...




Summoners, 

We will be performing a maintenance on 26/11 at 04:00 AM, where we will need to bring the EUW Platform offline. 

Following up on the...
```

Comment: I've just done that by myself! Well, a sort of! :) Your code is more clear than mine! :) Thanks for the answer anyway, I'll change my code with your version! :)

Comment: Even better if you figured it out for yourself first :) Glad to help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample:

```
public static final String text = "" +
    "<table><tr class=\"even\"> <!-- Title -->\n" +
    "    <td class=\"title riot\"\n" +
    "        title=\"Summoners, We will be performing Live Maintenance on the 26/11 at 04:00 AM, where we will need to bring the EUW Platform offline. Following up...\">\n" +
    "    </td>\n" +
    "</tr>\n" +
    "<tr class=\"odd\">\n" +
    "    <!-- Title -->\n" +
    "    <td class=\"title riot\"\n" +
    "        title=\"Summoners, welcome to the Service Status forum! Here you can come to see information regarding ongoing issues or events that we are currently working...\">\n" +
    "    </td>\n" +
    "</tr></table>";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(text);

    //System.out.println("your doc:" + doc);

    for (Element element : doc.select("tr > td")) {
        System.out.println(element.attr("title"));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Summoners, We will be performing Live Maintenance on the 26/11 at 04:00 AM, where we will need to bring the EUW Platform offline. Following up...
Summoners, welcome to the Service Status forum! Here you can come to see information regarding ongoing issues or events that we are currently working...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the source page is a web page, so I need to connecto to it. Moreover, after that code, there's other code, included in the same class.